# ReCreating Thread in Visual C++

Tags: multithreading, mfc

I have created a `CWinThread m_pThread` object using `AfxBeginThread()`. Then I needed to destroy that. After some operation I needed to create thread again. I called `AfxBeginThread()` again.

I got message `this may be due to corruption of the heap...`. I didn't do anything in the thread for testing. still I found the bug.

I destroyed thread by these.

```
    enter code here
     bool bRet = TerminateThread(m_pThread->m_hThread, -1);
  delete m_pThread;     
  m_pThread->m_hThread = NULL;      
  m_pThread = NULL;
```

Comment: You should never use `TerminateThread` - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx) warns against it.

Comment: CWinThread class has `BOOL m_bAutoDelete` member which is TRUE by default (possibly for VB programmers). Possibly you delete the object which is already deleted. And of course, never use `TerminateThread`.

Comment: Instead of creating and destroying a thread again and again you could use a thread pool. It's more convenient, less code and works faster. Read the MSDN documentation about what is recommended in .NET

Comment: After deleting m_pThread you are writing into the memory you deleted.

Comment: @Peter MFC is not .NET. What works for .NET is not even available in MFC (thread pools). Reusing a thread, however, is possible.

Comment: Reusing the thread is the way to use it I had in mind. Code reuse is good.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the lifetime of the thread make sure you switch OFF m_bAutoDelete, e.g.

```
m_pThread = AfxBeginThread( DoWork, NULL, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED );
if ( m_pThread ) {
    m_pThread->m_bAutoDelete = FALSE;
    m_pThread->ResumeThread();
}
```